Google OR Tools with time window constraints not able to properly allocate nodes within given time window
I'm trying to solve, vehicle routing problem with time window constraints, for this I'm using Google OR Tool's python library. Solution that I get is not following the provided time windows.
following is the code I'm using:
def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data_dict = {}
    data_dict["time_matrix"] = time_matrix.values.tolist()
    data_dict["time_windows"] = time_window["time_windows"].values.tolist()
    data_dict["num_vehicles"] = num_vehicles
    data_dict["depot"] = 0
    data_dict["demands"] = [0] + [1] * (len(time_matrix) - 1)
    data_dict["vehicle_capacities"] = [12]*data_dict["num_vehicles"]
    data_dict["vehicle_load_time"] = 5
    data_dict["vehicle_unload_time"] = 5


    return data_dict


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):

    print('Objective: {} miles'.format(solution.ObjectiveValue()))
    route_distance = 0
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("Time")
    for vehicle_id in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
        print(f"Vehicle = {vehicle_id}")
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route:\n'
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)
            arrival_time = solution.Min(time_dimension.CumulVar(index))
            departure_time = solution.Max(time_dimension.CumulVar(index))
            time_window = data['time_windows'][node_index]
            print(f"Client id {node_index}: Arrival Time {arrival_time}, Departure Time {departure_time} | Time Window {time_window}")

            plan_output += f' {node_index} ({arrival_time}) ->'
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(previous_index, index, 0)
        plan_output += f' {manager.IndexToNode(index)}\n'
        print(plan_output)
        print('Route time: {} minutes'.format(route_distance))
    
    

def get_routes(solution, routing, manager):
  # Get vehicle routes from a solution and store them in an array.
  # Get vehicle routes and store them in a two dimensional array whose
  # i,j entry is the jth location visited by vehicle i along its route.
  routes = []
  for route_nbr in range(routing.vehicles()):
    index = routing.Start(route_nbr)
    route = [manager.IndexToNode(index)]
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
      index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
      route.append(manager.IndexToNode(index))
    routes.append(route)
  return routes


def optimize():
    
    # Instantiate the data problem
    data_dict = create_data_model()
    
    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        len(data_dict["time_matrix"]), data_dict["num_vehicles"], data_dict["depot"]
    )
    
    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data_dict["time_matrix"][from_node][to_node]
    
    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)
    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)
    
    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    
    # Add Capacity constraint.
    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data_dict["demands"][from_node]

    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data_dict["vehicle_capacities"],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        "Capacity",
    )
    
    max_time_truck_can_travel = 540 ## 9hr

    # Add Time Windows constraint.
    time = "Time"
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        30,  # allow waiting time
        max_time_truck_can_travel,  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        time,
    )
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
    
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data_dict["time_windows"]):
        if location_idx == data_dict["depot"]:
            continue
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetMax(max_time_truck_can_travel)

    # Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
    depot_idx = data_dict["depot"]
    for vehicle_id in range(data_dict["num_vehicles"]):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
            round(data_dict["time_windows"][depot_idx][0]), round(data_dict["time_windows"][depot_idx][1])
        )
        
    # Instantiate route start and end times to produce feasible times.
    for i in range(data_dict["num_vehicles"]):
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i))
        )
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))
        
    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    )
    search_parameters.local_search_operators.use_shortest_path_swap_active = "BOOL_FALSE"
    
    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    
    if solution:
        print_solution(data_dict, manager, routing, solution)
        result = get_routes(solution, routing, manager)
    else:
        print("No Solution exist")
        result = []
        
    return result

Also it would be helpful if you can provide details (like how to configure) about slack (allow waiting time) and capacity(maximum time per vehicle) in below function
time = "Time"
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        30,  # allow waiting time
        max_time_truck_can_travel,  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        time,
    )
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)

tried scaling time matrix and window, this makes the optimizer to run for forever.
Also played around with slack and capacity argument of add dimension function.
